# What are Stacks and Queues, contiguous or linked data structures?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

I'm actually reading skiena book " Algothm design manual " and it says that there are two types of data structures:

• Contiguously-allocated structures are composed of single slabs of memory, and
include arrays, matrices, heaps, and hash tables.

• Linked data structures are composed of distinct chunks of memory bound
together by pointers, and include lists, trees, and graph adjacency lists.

But i did not see Stacks and Queues . contiguous or Linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement them in both ways. Stacks and queues are abstract data types, not data structures, so they only expose an interface and not an implementation. For example, you could implement a stack using a linked list or using an array. You do not know the underlying implementation when using a stack, instead you know what data it can store and different accessors.

More concretely, consider a stack. You can choose to represent it using an array, which can use doubling strategy as it gets larger. You can take an integer value representing the index at which the stack gets up to, and then you will keep moving that integer pointer forward. Similarly, for linked lists, you can choose to have a linked list representing the stack and you would have a backwards link so that you can pop.

Comment: Queues and stacks may also be called as _abstract data structures_, so I wouldn't claim that a queue or a stack is not a data structure, it is not that well defined